# Is it necessary to relaese any control or var in deal loc method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, dealloc

I have view control with five button i am setting there properties also is it necessary to release them in dealloc thanks

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController{
    IBOutlet UIButton*homeButton;
    IBOutlet UIButton*economicDataButton;
    IBOutlet UIButton*riskButton;
    IBOutlet UIButton*financialImpactButton;
    IBOutlet UIButton*probabilitiesButton;
    IBOutlet UIButton*enterButton;
}
```

Comment: Are you using ARC? You don't release at all if using arc, you only manage strong and weak references. I would suggest using properties instead of ivars as well.

Comment: how to use ARC i did not have any idea i am using iOS5 and xcode 4.3

Comment: There's no reason to still be on Xcode 4.3, you can update to latest and still target iOS 5. I would suggest learning about ARC to simplify your memory management. ARC is available on iOS 5.

Comment: it mean how to identify that i am using ARC in project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in ARC you don't have to. the system does it for you. but if you are not using arc then you may do it. even when i use arc or partial arc just for a few classes i still do it. i guess i'm a paranoid coder.:)

EDIT:

well if it is your project and you started it then you must check the box at the beginning for using automatic reference counting or not checking it. if you are using a sample project from someone else then go the target level of your project. then you go to built phases and expand that and see if this phrase is in front of anyone of them. -fobjc-arc. that is for the projects that started without arc and then arc was added to some classes. on the hand if the entire project is arc enabled just declare a iboutlet and try to synthesis it and project will give you an error asking for storng or weak reference. that's how you know that entire project is arc enabled.
happy coding my friend

Comment: how to check wether project is uisng ARC or not

Comment: does my answer gives you any help in solving your issue or you need more assistance?